# Create a NodaTime LocalDate representing "today"

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

What is the recommended way to create a LocalDate instance that represents "today". I was expecting there to be a static "Now" or "Today" property in the LocalDate class, but there isn't. My current approach is to use DateTime.Now:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
LocalDate today = new LocalDate(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First recognize that when you say "today", the answer could be different for different people in different parts of the world.   Therefore, in order to get the current local date, you must have a time zone in mind.

Noda Time correctly models this by giving you an `Instant` when you call `Now` from an `IClock` implementation such as the system clock.   An instant is universal, so you just need to convert it to some time zone to get that time zone's local date.

```
// get the current time from the system clock
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;

// get a time zone
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Tokyo"];

// use now and tz to get "today"
LocalDate today = now.InZone(tz).Date;
```

That's the minimal code.  Of course, if you want to use the computer's local time zone (like you did with `DateTime.Now`), you can get it like so:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
```

And to really implement it properly, you should call `.Now` from the `IClock` interface, such that you could substitute the system clock with a fake clock for your unit tests.

This is a great example of how Noda Time intentionally doesn't hide things from you.  All this is still going on under the hood when you call `DateTime.Now`, but you just don't see it.  [You can read more about Noda Time's design philosophy in the user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/design.html).

Answer (score 26):

Matt's answer is spot on for Noda Time 1.x.

In Noda Time 2.0, I'm introducing a `ZonedClock`, which is basically a combination of `IClock` and a `DateTimeZone`. As you're likely to want the current time in the same time zone multiple times, you can inject that (I'm assuming you're using dependency injection) and retain that, then use it. For example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private readonly ZonedClock clock;

    internal SomeClass(ZonedClock clock)
    { 
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    internal void DoSomethingWithDate()
    {
        LocalDate today = clock.GetCurrentDate();
        ...
    }
}
```

You would normally provide the `ZonedClock` by taking an `IClock` and using one of the new extension methods, e.g.

```
var clock = SystemClock.Instance;
var zoned = clock.InUtc();
// Or...
var zoned = clock.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
// Or...
var zoned = clock.InTzdbSystemDefaultZone();
// Or...
var zoned = clock.InBclSystemDefaultZone();
```

Note that your 1.x code won't work in 2.x anyway - I'm removing the `Now` property from `IClock` as it really shouldn't be a property (given the way it changes) - it's now a `GetCurrentInstant()` method.;

Comment: I like it.  2.0 is looking better all the time!

Comment: What lifetime should `ZonedClock` be registered as when using DI?

Comment: @Oskar: I don't really know how to answer that. Do you always want the same clock? Do you always want the same time zone? Use the answers to those questions to drive your choice.

Comment: I always want the same time zone. Is there any downside with using the same clock?

Comment: @Oskar: Almost certainly not - but you're the one with all the context here. There's nothing special going on from the Noda Time side.

Answer (score 8):

Jon's answer is right, but I think it is helpful to put it all together.  For NodaTime 2.x:

```
SystemClock.Instance.InTzdbSystemDefaultZone().GetCurrentLocalDateTime().Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Patrick's answer is correct.
But, you may want to get `Now` for the current user's timezone instead of system's timezone.
For NodaTime 3.x:

```cs
//Tz is a DateTimeZone object, constructed from current user's preferred timezone ID
SystemClock.Instance.InZone(Tz).GetCurrentZonedDateTime();
```

You can also use `GetCurrentLocalDateTime` or `GetCurrentOffsetDateTime` based on your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDate today = DateTime.Now.ToLocalDateTime().Date;
```